# In Prolog is the use of variables in facts a common practice?

Tags: prolog

I came across this example of a fact in Prolog:

```
vertical(line(point(X,Y),point(X,Z))).
```

This seems strange to me as I thought facts always contain only a functor and atoms (or structures of atoms) and the above code seems more like a rule (if .... then line is vertical).

This has really confused me and I am now trying to figure out the difference between a fact containing variables and a rule and when one or the other should be used. Someone please help me out! :S

Also, how could I write this code using rules?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Technically, yes, you can have variables in facts, and it is common practice. Although, I suppose they might then become rules. :)

Let's consider your example:

```
vertical(line(point(X,Y),point(X,Z))).
```

This is an implicit way of expressing the following rule:

```
vertical(line(point(X1,Y), point(X2,Z))) :- X1 = X2.
```

This of course would give a warning about `Y` and `Z` being singleton variables. Since you don't care what they are, you can use `_` and express the rule as follows:

```
vertical(line(point(X1,_), point(X2,_))) :- X1 = X2.
```

Or, simply:

```
vertical(line(point(X,_), point(X,_))).
```

One definition of "fact" versus "rule" is given in this article on [Facts, Rules, and Queries](http://www.cs.trincoll.edu/~ram/cpsc352/notes/prolog/factsrules.html). Following this definition, the above could be considered a fact since it would be true for all `X`.